# Same request for same content on two different websites

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have two different websites with almost the same web page, it's like a portfolio with logos and links on every logos, i would like to know if it's possible when i update the portfolio on the first website, it could also update the other website

I have no idea how i could do that (or pay someone to do that btw if we need to develop something special) but it could be very useful for us, (time saved)

Don't hesitate to ask me more details if you think you could help me
Thank you again for reading me
Best

Comment: what you could do is use create API for both websites and call it after you successfully update the logo on the first site, so the API will change the logo on the other site as well.

Comment: You could store all of the portfolio details in a database, and then have both websites share the same database (or an API that interacts with this database).